# Tricky and confusing C program about divisor sum and perfect numbers

Tags: c

The assignment is :

Write a program that calculates the sum of the divisors of a number from input.

A number is considered perfect if the sum of it's divisiors equal the number (ex: 6 = 1+2+3 ;28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 +14).

Another definition:
a perfect number is a number that is half the sum of all of its positive divisors (including itself)

Generate the first k perfect numbers (k<150).

The main problem with this is that it's confusing the two asking points don't really relate.

In this program i calculated the sum of divisors of an entered number, but i don't know how to relate it with the second point (Generate the first k perfect numbers (k<150)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main()
{
int x,i,y,div,suma,k;
printf("Introduceti numarul\n");          \\enter the number
scanf("%d",&x);
suma=0;                                   \\sum is 0
for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
{

if(x%i==0)
suma=suma+i;                \\sum=sum+i;
}
printf("Suma divizorilor naturali este: %d\n",suma);      \\the sum of the divisors is

for(k=1;k<150;k++)               \\ bad part
{
if (x==suma)
printf("%d",k);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function which can tell whether a given integer is perfect or not:

```
int isPerfect(int);
```

(function body not shown)

Now your main program will look like:

```
int candidate;
int perfectNumbers;

for(candidate = 1, perfectNumbers = 0; perfectNumbers < 150; candidate++) {
  if (isPerfect(candidate)) {
    printf("Number %d is perfect\n", candidate);
    perfectNumbers++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
For the same program without functions:

```
int candidate;
int perfectNumbers;

for(candidate = 1, perfectNumbers = 0; perfectNumbers < 150; candidate++) {

  [... here your algorithm to compute the sum of the divisors of "candidate" ...]

  if (candidate*2 == sum_of_divisors) {
    printf("Number %d is perfect\n", candidate);
    perfectNumbers++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:** Just a note on perfect numbers

As noted in the comments section below, perfect numbers are very rare, only 48th of them are known as of 2014. The sequence ([A000396](https://oeis.org/A000396)) also grows very fast: using 64-bit integers you'll be able to compute up to the 8th perfect number (which happen to be 2,305,843,008,139,952,128). In this case the variable `candidate` will wrap around and start "finding" "new" perfect numbers from the beginning (until 150 of them are found: actually 19 repetitions of the only 8 findable in 64-bit integers). Note though that your algorithm must not choke on a `candidate` equals to `0` or to negative numbers (only to `0` if you declare `candidate` as `unsigned int`).

Comment: Watch out though: as of 2013 there are only 48 known perfect numbers ([List of Perfect Numbers at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers)); from the 7th number you'll need more than 32 bits (for `candidate`); from the 8th the storage jumpshots to 60 bits !!!

Comment: Thanks, but can't use functions yet would seem like i copied it. Is there a way to do this using loops?

Comment: Just another comment on the known perfect numbers: the 48th (largest known) needs a whooping 115770323 bits of storage. That's about 14 Mb just to store the number.

Comment: @Stack_token yes, you can put the computation of whether the number is perfect or not just after the `for`. I'll edit the answer to point this.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question to mean generate all numbers under 150 that could are perfect numbers.

Therefore, if your program works for calculating perfect numbers, you keep calculating them until the starting number is `>= 150`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, but how would you go about that?

Comment: Are you able to properly go about calculating whether or not a given number is perfect?

Comment: @Stack_token: You have to nest your loops: Your second loop goes outside. The first loop must re-evaluate the divisor sum for each `k`. Throw out the user input and replace `x` with `k` in the inner loop.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new at this and very tired , could you psot that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my solution ..

First, you have to make a reliable way of getting divisors.
Here's a function I made for that:

```
size_t
getdivisors(num, divisors)
    long long num;
    long long *divisors;
{
    size_t divs = 0;
    for(long long i = num; i > 0; --i)
        if (num%i == 0)
            divisors[divs++] = i;
    return divs;
}
```

Second, you need to check if the number's divisors match the perfect number's divisors properties (the sum of them is half the number).
Here's a second function for that:

```
bool
isperfect(num)
    long long num;
{
    long long divisors[num/2+1];
    size_t divs = getdivisors(num, divisors);
    if (divs == 0)
        return false;
    long long n = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < divs; ++i)
        n += divisors[i];
    return (n == num);
}
```

Now, from your question, I think you need to print all perfect numbers less than 150, right ?
See this:

```
int
main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    char ** argv;
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 150; ++i)
        if (isperfect(i))
            printf("%d is perfect.\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that answers your question ..